# how to handle non-breaking hyphen in text between range in word?

Tags: c#, text, ms-word, range

I have some text with non-breaking hyphen in word. I need that text as it is in output. But am getting text with non-breaking hyphen removed.

```
Word.Range rangeObj = _wordDoc.Range(ref x, ref y);
txt += rangeObj.Text;
```

I am using the above code. And in txt variable I am getting output but with non breaking hyphen removed. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [mdsn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195101.aspx). Chr(160) = nonbreaking space is not  the plain text symbol.
`Range.FormattedText` can you help?

Comment: @James How is Rahul's suggestion "not working" for you? What is it you actually need/want to do with the text that contains special characters?

Comment: @Cindy, I want to get it as hyphen in txt. for example- suppose there are 2 lines in word document. 1. normal-hyphen 2. non-breaking hyphen. when I am reading rangeObj.Text I want both the text with hyphen. but am getting 1.normal-hyphen 2. nonbreaking hyphen.  there is no hyphen in 2.

Comment: You didn't mention replacing hyphen with non breaking hyphen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txt = Regex.Replace(txt, "[\u001e|\u2011|\u2013|\u2014]", "-");
```

I got 1 solution for this. we can replace non-breaking hyphen with normal hyphen by using above line of code:

Comment: You didn't told us that you want to replace nonbreaking hyphen with simple hyphen coz its very simple in ms word's find property.

Comment: Your regex confuses alternation with character class syntax. A character class matches any one of the characters between the square brackets, e.g. [abc], not to be confused with (a|b|c). What your regex does is replace any pipe characters (|) with hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question to be: How to replace any non-breaking hyphens (ANSI 30) in a text string read from a Word Range with a normal dash (ANSI 45).

This can be done in VBA using the `Replace` function. For example:

```
txt = Replace(rangeObj.Text, Chr(30), "-")
```

C# uses the tools provided by the .NET Framework, of course. Here it's the `Replace` method, which can replace a String with a String or a Char with a Char. Since the non-breaking hyphen needs to be represented by its character code, the Char overload correct. For example:

```
 string selText = wdApp.Selection.Text;
 char cDash = (char) 45;
 char cNonBreakHyph = (char) 30;
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(selText.Replace(cNonBreakHyph, cDash));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about c# but in VBA `Range.FormattedText` just works fine. Try `rangeObj.FormattedText`.

For example this works fine in VBA.

```
Sub test()
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range
        s = oRng.FormattedText
        oRng.InsertAfter s
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Metod can not work, because of we use interface method of object `range` see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ff192541.aspx) Write your code using  `Range.FormattedText` and code error!